# Access Parallels VM files

Tags: unix, filesystem, development, parallels-desktop

I just finished an install of my debian (7.8) on parallels virtual machine and I'd love to be able to share the linux folders with the osx platform. Any ideas on how that might be done ?
Problem with google is that most people talk about windows or doing it the other way around (which is easy).

Context: the company I'm working for installed their development environment on a VM on my mac. I can access the localhost of the VM from osx but I also have to work on the files, which would be easier if I could do so in osx for thousands of good and bad reasons.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something I do myself, so I am not certain of the safety of it, however…

Right click the .pvm file & Open With - Parallels Mounter

This will give you access to the drive contents, including write access.

Comment: Actually I already tried that. I apparently don't have the rights to do so !

Comment: That may be initial perms on the VM's 'drive' itself. I don't have any nix as VM, only Win, but simple 'get info' on something like the C:\windows folder itself shows I have 'custom' perms. BatChmod thinks I have rwxrwxrwx so there may be 'competition' between the two authorities, I'm really not certain.